# Непонятная ситуация при сортировке массивов

Tags: objective-c

Всем привет. Столкнулся со странной проблемой.

Сравниваю 2 массива - в одном строки, в другом - свой класс с пропертью строкового типа.
При сравнении строк буква Ё становится перед Е, а во втором случае наоборот.

```
[names sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(NSString *obj1, NSString *obj2) {
        return [obj1 compare:obj2];
    }];

[self.sections sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(Section *obj1, Section *obj2) {
        return [obj1.name compare:obj2.name];
    }];
```

Кто-нибудь может подсказать, из-за чего так?

Comment: не получается воспроизвести